# Vue Component Reactive V-Model from parent update

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm struggling with attempting to make a Jquery plugin into a Vue Component. I have everything else working but I somehow need to detect when the v-model value is changed from the parent of the child component. For instance, if something else in the vue app changed the bound value on the child component I need to run some specific code. Here is what I have so far I haven't been able to figure out how specifically to detect this:

```
Vue.component(
            'c5-page-selector',
            {
                template: '<div class="page-selector"></div>',
                prop: ['value'],
                mounted: function () {
                    let self = this;
                    $(this.$el).concretePageSelector({inputName: 'test', cID: this.value});
                    $(this.$el).find('.ccm-item-selector-clear').click(function () {
                        self.updatePage();
                    });

                    $(this.$el).click(function () {
                        self.updatePage();
                    });
                    Concrete.event.bind('ConcreteSitemap', function(e, instance) {
                        var instance = instance;
                        Concrete.event.bind('SitemapSelectPage', function(e, data) {
                            if (data.instance == instance) {
                                self.updatePage();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                methods: {
                    updatePage() {
                        let value = $(this.$el).find('input').val();
                        if (value && value.length && value != 0) {
                            value = parseInt(value, 10);
                        } else {
                            value = null;
                        }
                        this.$emit('input', value)
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: use a watcher to watch for prop change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
computed: {
  yourDesiredVariable: {
     get() {
       return this.value
     },
     set(val) {
       this.$emit('input', val)
     }
  }
}
```

Try outputting the yourDesiredValue in DOM